# How can I show rating:entries that contain both ratings AND reviews?

Tags: solspace, solspace-rating

I'm using the Solspace Rating module and I'd like to be able to display rating:entries that contain a review.

It seems like I can exclude unrated or show only unrated, but how can I filter to show only rating:entries with both a numeric rating AND a review?

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with conditionals inside the rating:entries loop to test to see if the rating field is filled:

```
{if review}
Show the rating entry
{/if}
```

In the example above "review" is the name of the review field.

But that means you won't get an accurate `{if rating_no_results}` because the tag could still return results that are not displayed due to the conditional.